# Is there a function to skip repeating values being written into text file?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get all hyperlinks from an array that match the word "contacts" into .csv text file. The problem is if it finds another contact hyperlink on the same website it will print it again. How do I fix this? Also how to web scrape multiple websites for specific div that contains keywords: ("Phone number", "Address", "E-mail" and etc.)?

```
private void contactbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList domainlist = new ArrayList();  
        const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
        // -- Location of domain list file --
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/domains.txt"))           
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                domainlist.Add(line);
        }
        foreach (string s in domainlist)
        {
            SearchHyperlinks("https://" + s);
        }
    }



public static void SearchHyperlinks(string address4)
    {

        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(address4);

        
        String GetAbsoluteUrlString(string baseUrl, string url)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                uri = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), uri);
            return uri.ToString();
        }      
        try
        {
            using (var w = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/hyperlink.csv"))
                foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(., 'Contacts') or starts-with(., 'contacts') or starts-with(., 'CONTACTS') or starts-with (., 'Shop Contacts')]"))
                {
                    String hrefValue = link.Attributes["href"].Value;

                    if (hrefValue != null)
                    {
                        String fullhref = GetAbsoluteUrlString(address4, hrefValue);
                        Console.WriteLine(fullhref);
                        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/hyperlinks.csv", true))
                        {
                            var writer = new CsvWriter(textWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            writer.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                            writer.WriteField(fullhref);
                            writer.NextRecord();
                        }
                    }

                }
        }

        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hyperlinks not found");
        }
```

Comment: LINQ's `Distinct`. Or store the data in a `HashSet`.

Comment: What are you using `ArrayList` for? Are you reading a book back from 2001?

Comment: Try this: `var domainlist = File.ReadLines(@"C:/Users/Username/Desktop/domains.txt").Distinct().ToList();`.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your method to actually **Search**, and not **Write**:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SearchHyperlinks(string address4)
{
    var hw = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = hw.Load(address4);

    String GetAbsoluteUrlString(string baseUrl, string url)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            uri = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), uri);
        return uri.ToString();
    }
    var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(., 'Contacts') or starts-with(., 'contacts') or starts-with(., 'CONTACTS') or starts-with (., 'Shop Contacts')]");
    if(links == null)
       yield return break;
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        var hrefValue = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
        if (hrefValue != null)
        {
            var fullhref = GetAbsoluteUrlString(address4, hrefValue);
            yield return fullhref;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you distinct values returned:

```
var distinct = SearchHyperlinks(input).Distinct();
```

Then you write them all wherever you want.